# Error reading OrderedDict from JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

so i have this code:

```
resLoad = json.loads(r3.text, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)[u'updateResults']
print(resLoad)
print(resLoad['success'])
```

the line

```
print(resLoad)
```

returns the following

```
[OrderedDict([('objectId', 29), ('globalId', None), ('success', True)])]
```

but when i try and read the success result with

```
print(resLoad['success'])
```

i get an error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Stu

Comment: what is ``r3.text``? Please as the relevant part of the string to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resLoad` is a list of dicts with a single dictionary (as indicated by the sqaure brackets). Try `print(resLoad[0]['success'])`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, that worked, why does that work over naming the dictionary i want? thanks again